# MySQL query truncate table then insert

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, truncate, workbench

I have this query:

```
load data local infile 'C:/Users/vissia18/Desktop/report-1394508761.csv' into table report    fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines
(order_num, sales_order_item, sku, description, unit_price, tax_amount, coupon_money_value, coupon_percent, coupon_refundable, paid_price, created_date, created_time, wrapping_price, refund_type, refund_money, refund_shipping_money, refunded_other_money, refund_info, bank_reference, cart_rule_discount, return_tracking_num, shipment_type, current_unit_cost, created_unit_cost, item_status, item_status_date, canceled_reason, coupon_code, cust_id, cust_first_name, cust_last_name, cust_email, cust_gender, payment_method, grand_total);
```

I'm using MySQL workbench. What is needed is that if there is a same order_num, it will overwrite that row. I still don'w know how to do that that's why what I'm trying to do now is to TRUNCATE the table then load the csv file again in the table.

```
truncate table report;
```

Because of that, I will be doing two queries. Is there a way to query both the truncate and load data in file in just one query? And if possible, how can I overwrite a row if it has the same order_num?

Comment: What's wrong with 2 queries?

Comment: the user will not be IT related. he just want to click then voila, both queries should be executed.

Comment: how do you run the program? Why can't you put those 2 queries in the event of button click or something?

Comment: i can if it's a program. he will just be using workbench or something.  I will be making the database and the query then pass it to him. but he's not IT literate that's why I need to make it simple.

Comment: then make a SP.. in your SP call those 2 queries.

Comment: So if a person will copy this query anyway, why do you think having 2 queries `query 1; query 2;` will be more tricky for a person to copy-paste than a single query?

Comment: makes sense but this is just my option. im still searching on a way to overwrite the row with the same order_num. im trying to make it simpler.